# MenuItems IsHighlighted

Tags: .net, wpf, background, menuitem

Below works fine BEFORE any MenuItem is selected (clicked) - I get green on mouse over (IsHighlighted = true).
After any MenuItem is selected (clicked) the background of the IsHighlighted goes back to the default gray.
How do I set Background of the IsHighlighted after any MenuItem is selected?
Rather how do I get the IsHighlighted color to stick?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Note if I click another item not on the menu then come back to the menu IsHighlighted is Green.

Same problem with IsMouseOver.  It loses the color (goes back to the default gray) after any MenuItem is selected.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="View">
            <CheckBox Name="DocViewNative" VerticalAlignment="Center">ViewNative</CheckBox>
            <CheckBox Name="DocViewIRPO"   VerticalAlignment="Center">ViewIPRO</CheckBox>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Admin">
            <MenuItem Header="Snapshot Admin" />
            <MenuItem Header="Tags Admin" />  
            <MenuItem Header="Thesaurus Admin" />
        </MenuItem>            
        <MenuItem Header="Reload"/>
    </Menu>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Menu IsHighlighted background changes after click any MenuItems" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Click me to get green back"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem now. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you've currently got this:

[image]

And you want this:

[image]

But you're getting this:

[image]

If you inspect the `MenuItem`'s `ControlTemplate`, the problem actually lies in a couple of Triggers which are changing the Rectangle's Fill (which is bound to Background) to a static brush. Therefore, it doesn't matter what Background you set in a setter; it's going to be ignored. You can fix this by re-templating the MenuItem and removing the commented lines:

```
<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#E0717070"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#28717070" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#50717070" Offset="0.75"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#90717070" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>-->
    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50747272"/>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#E0717070"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#28717070" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#50717070" Offset="0.75"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#90717070" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>-->
    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50747272"/>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: I am asking how do I set Background of the IsHighlighted after any MenuItem is selected?   No I am not asking about just the item clicked "after any".

Comment: IsMouseOver also loses it color after any MenuItem is clicked.

Comment: What is so hard about the IsHighlighted color is green until I click any  MenuItem and then then IsHighlighted color reverts back to the default gray?  IsHighlighted is a behavior and I don't want to change that behavior.  I already stated that IsMouseOver has the same problem.

Comment: thanks.  I will look at it tomorrow.  But I am not used to these  8 digit value.